# Javascript + HTML change html according to mobile size

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

What I'm trying to accomplish can't be done with media queries from CSS.

```
<div class='bottom'>
    <div class='left'>
        <input type='submit' class='default' value='<?php echo order; ?>'/>
    </div>
    <div class='right'>
        <input type='submit' class='default' value='<?php echo clear; ?>'/>
        <input type='submit' class='default' value='<?php echo save; ?>'/>
    </div>
</div>
```

This code works perfectly in screens > 533px - mostly tablets, but in smaller screens (mobile) the two last buttons overlaps the bottom.

I don't want to ellipsis the text from the first button, I want to create another line of the class 'bottom'. Something like this:

```
<div class='bottom'>
    <div class='right'>
        <input type='submit' class='default' value='<?php echo clear;?>'/>
        <input type='submit' class='default' value='<?php echo save;?>'/>
    </div>
</div>
<div class='bottom'>
    <div class='left'>
        <input type='submit' class='default' value='<?php echo order; ?>'/>
    </div>
</div>
```

As you see I've PHP inside the html, which means I can't remove the whole divs and create another in Javascript (because it won't get that PHP code).

The final solution is to duplicate the **class bottom**, delete **class left** in the original **class bottom**, and delete **class right** in the duplicated **class bottom**.

```
if (window.matchMedia('(min-device-width: 533px)').matches) {
    var class_bottom = $(".bottom").html(); // duplicated

    $(".bottom .left").remove(); // works
    $(class_bottom + " .right").remove(); // doesn't work
    $(class_bottom).insertAfter($(".bottom")); // doesn't work
}
```

Thanks guys, **solved**.

```
if (window.matchMedia('(min-device-width: 533px)').matches) {
    var class_bottom = $(".bottom").clone(); // nice trick

    $(".bottom .left").remove();
    $(class_bottom).find('.right').remove(); // remove right on clone
    $(class_bottom).insertAfter($(".bottom")); // insert AFTER the original class
}
```

Comment: what is your question? + Please add a demo do sowcase the problem. I'm quite sure there will be a simple solution

Comment: @DonJuwe, basically, I want help to make this works in javascript..where it says "doesn't work".

Comment: @NicoO I'll try to make JSfiddle.

Answer (score 0):

You might need to look for a responsive layout by using bootstrap 3. Bootstrap 3 can solve the above mentioned issue...
[The Bootstrap library](http://getbootstrap.com/css/)